# How to get data from Excel into SQL Server using Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I want to insert data from Excel into SQL Server. I have written code but the values are not being read from Excel:

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();                

Workbook WB = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;    
Sheets worksheets = WB.Worksheets;    
lastrow = WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;                         

for(int i = 2; i<= lastrow; i++)      
{    
     cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT Table_1 (emp_no,emp_name,salary) values (WB.Cells[i , 1] , WB.Cells[i , 2] , WB.Cells[i , 3]))");                    
}
```

Comment: How about `INSERT INTO Table_1 ...`?

Comment: checked itz not working.. and tried by adding '"&WB.cells[i,1]&"' also not working.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 2):

## Strongly not recommended, but working solution:

```
for(int i = 2; I <= lastrow; i++)      
{    
    cmd.CommandText = ($"INSERT INTO Table_1 (emp_no,emp_name,salary) VALUES ({WB.Cells[i, 1]}, {WB.Cells[i, 2]}, {WB.Cells[i, 3]}))");                    
}
```

Please don't use this and read about [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) for why **not** to use it!

Do yourself a favor and use [parametrized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: For future reference... does the $ mean that you can use code variables inside text?

Comment: Yes, kind of, it's the string interpolation operator, which allows for use of C# code inside of the the `{}` in the string. [further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)